# In Solr, how to sort documents differently based on their attributes?

Tags: sorting, solr, sunspot

My documents have these 2 fields:

- **status**

  - open
  - upcoming
  - ended
- **end_date**

Right now I'm sorting this way:

`status_int ASC, end_date ASC` (status_int is just a way to easily order by status open -> upcoming -> ended)

For `open` and `upcoming` events, I want to show the ones that **end the soonest** first, that's why I have `end_date ASC`. The issue is that it doesn't work well for ended events, as the user will get the events from 2010 for instance before the ones that ended in 2020.

So, I'd like to order by `end_date ASC` for documents that dont have the ended status, and `end_date DESC` for the ended ones.

Is it possible to change the order based on a document attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of my head, an easy solution is to use streaming expressions, although the usability of them depends on some technical details (Solr version, your client implementation details etc.)

Start two search streams, one for documents which don't have the ended status, and one for others. You can specify different sort criterias for two different streams. Then merge those two streams. Something like:

```
list(
    search(
        yourCollection,
        q="yourQuery",
        qt="/export", //or "/select" based on your needs
        fq="*:* AND NOT status:ended",
        sort="end_date asc"
    ),
    search(
        yourCollection,
        q="yourQuery",
        qt="/export", //or "/select" based on your needs
        fq="status:ended",
        sort="end_date desc"
    )
)
```

this will first return not-ended ones sorted by end_date asc, and after them status=ended ones sorted by end_date desc. You can also sort them again based on some other condition, or merge them differently based on your requirements.

---

Another simpler solution could be using function queries and pseudo fields, something along the lines of:

> &fl=sortonthis:if(not(status=ended),rord(end_date),ord(end_date))&sort=sortonthis
> asc

I didn't test but it should work with some tweaks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with the pseudo field approach.

Comment: In the end, we went with a different approach. We're converting the dates to integers (Unix time), and we're making them negative if the date is in the past (we're already reindexing the events when the end_date passes anyway). This way, recently ended events have a "higher" absolute value than the ones that ended before, but since it's negative, it'll be a lower integer, so sorting ASC will work out how we need it to.

Answer (score 0):

If `end_date` is always in the future for events that haven't ended, you can probably make it work by using `abs(ms(NOW, end_date))` - it'll give you a value that represents how far from the current date the end date is.

Comment: At what level would you do this? I'm using Sunspot, which is a rails gem, so I'm very familiar at all with how solr queries are written. And do you have a guess on the performance hit? Would it be equivalent to the pseudo field approach suggested above? Or are you suggesting that I use this expression in the pseudo field? Ty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sunspot in detail, so I wouldn't know. For performance, test both suggestions and see which one performs good enough.